# Java - comparision fields using reflection

Tags: java

I need compare all fields of two objects and return number of differences.

Pseudocode looks like below:

```
public int differentFields(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {
    int differentFields = 0;
   for all fields of foo1 and foo2:
       if foo1.field[i] != foo2.field[i]
           differentFields++;

   return differentFields;
}
```

Fields have the same names because I want to compare objects of the same class.

I cannot do that using standard equals because Foo has a lot of fields and I would have to write too much if statements.

How can I do that using reflection?

Comment: Why you just don't use standard equals implementation for your class?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get with that???

Comment: totally overkill

Comment: Would be helpful if you give more details like what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Because if I would implement using equals code would be redundand.

Comment: And I would have to write if statement for all fields. It would be redundant.

Comment: Alternatively, ask your IDE to generate equals and hashcode for you, or use Lombok.

Comment: You don't understand what I have to do.
I have to count how many of fields values are different, but I don't want to use if statement for each field, because this is redundant.

Comment: I think we all understand what you want to do, but we all agree that it's probably a bad idea if the only reason you want this is to not have a few `if` statements. How many fields are we talking about here?

Comment: This is not important how many because now my object can have 5 fields and tomorrow can have 50.

Comment: All fields are public? Or are there some getter?

Comment: fields are private, but all have getters

Comment: How can it have different number of fields today and tomorrow? Do you want to use this method as an equals-replacement for different classes, or as a "future-proof" never-touch-again equals implementation? What if "tomorrow" one of the attributes is not relevant, e.g. some internal caching variable?

Comment: Since you want to compare instances of the same class, reflection is not the way to go here. You have access to all fields directly. Just because you could write a loop (which requires less statements) does not automatically mean it's the best solution. Also there's no redundancy at all!

Comment: How can I do that using loop?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it is a **bad idea** to use reflection to get all class members. This should solve your requirement:

```
public <T> int countDiff(T t1, T t2) throws Exception {
    int diffCount = 0;
    Class<? extends Object> tClass = t1.getClass();
    for (Field field : tClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value1 = field.get(t1);
        Object value2 = field.get(t2);
        if (!isEqual(value1, value2)) {
            diffCount++;
        }
    }
    return diffCount;
}

private boolean isEqual(Object v1, Object v2) {
    return (v1 == null && v2 == null) || (v1 != null && v1.equals(v2));
}
```

A quiet better solution would be to loop over the getter (but it is still a bad idea:

```
public <T> int countDiff(T t1, T t2) throws Exception {
    int diffCount = 0;
    Class<? extends Object> tClass = t1.getClass();
    for (Method method : tClass.getMethods()) {
        if (!isGetter(method)) {
            continue;
        }
        Object value1 = method.invoke(t1);
        Object value2 = method.invoke(t2);
        if (!isEqual(value1, value2)) {
            diffCount++;
        }
    }
    return diffCount;
}

private boolean isGetter(Method m) {
    boolean name = m.getName().startsWith("get") || m.getName().startsWith("is");
    return name && m.getParameterTypes().length == 0 && m.getReturnType() != Void.TYPE;
}

private boolean isEqual(Object v1, Object v2) {
    return (v1 == null && v2 == null) || (v1 != null && v1.equals(v2));
}
```

**EDIT** Thanks @tobias_k: also `is` methods for boolean added

Comment: Why do you think it is bad idea?

Comment: It is not common to use reflection. If you need to you should rethink your design (or in your case the requirement). I'm using reflection in some test classes but never in production...

Comment: The method using getters gets ugly when you have methods like `getSomethingByPerformingAwfullyComplexCalculation`. Also, some getters actually start with `is` (for booleans).

Comment: @tobias_k thanks, `isGetter` adjusted. And you're right but I think it is a bad design if a getter makes some expensive calculations.

Comment: This answer nicely illustrates that there's absolutely no way to reduce complexity. There will be some sort of price to pay. Always.